# Stack Overflow modifications to pagedown?

Tags: discussion, markdown, markdown-rendering

Are the pagedown modifications and toolbar for pagedown opensourced by Stack Exchange somewhere?

I really like their integration into [Imgur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imgur), and the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) stuff. I would like to use them on my personal projects.

What are the licensing of the minified JavaScript files available on Stack Exchange sites? Like [this](http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/wmd.en.js?v=370730f7025d) one.

Comment: jsfiddle stuff?

Answer (score 9):

Your question is a little confusing; I don't think the Imgur and Stack Snippets dialog boxes are modifications, they are plugins to the editor. I don't think they are available as OSS at this time, no.

*PageDown* is the project with all the modifications that Stack Exchange uses, based on the original *Showdown* and *WMD* projects. Yes, all those modifications are OSS.

From the [PageDown README](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/wiki/PageDown):

> PageDown is the JavaScript Markdown previewer used on Stack Overflow and the rest of the Stack Exchange network. It includes a Markdown-to-HTML converter and an in-page Markdown editor with live preview.
>
> [...]
>
> The largest part is based on work by John Fraser, a.k.a. Attacklab. He created the converter under the name Showdown and the editor under the name WMD.

Get your copy [from the Google Code project](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/); it is up-to-date by the looks of it. Note that user balpha is [Benjamin Dumke-von der Ehe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115866/balpha), a Stack Exchange employee.

I'd expect the minified versions to have the same license as the un-minified code; it's the same code after all, just run through a minifier.

The *Imgur Image dialog* is not part of the editor; the code defines a hook for swapping in your own dialog:

```js
hooks.addFalse("insertImageDialog");     /* called with one parameter: a callback to be called with the URL of the image. If the application creates
                                          * its own image insertion dialog, this hook should return true, and the callback should be called with the chosen
                                          * image url (or null if the user cancelled). If this hook returns false, the default dialog will be used.
                                          */
```

Similarly, there is no trace of the Stack Snippets dialog in the PageDown codebase, it must be similarly passed in in the editor options as an extra button.